# What is the purpose of using php inside css link tag?

Tags: php, web

I've come across this recently and don't understand. I've Googled, but not sure what I should be Googleing to find answers to my questions.

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/global.css<?=$debug?'?'.rand():''?>" />
```

I noticed something like this broke an entire website's styles.

Answer (score 2):

This appends a random number to the CSS URL if debug mode is on.
It's done to break caching.

Answer (score 1):

That particular php code intends to avoid that CSS resource being stored in a browser's cache. That's because you add a random string as a parameter to the HTTP request, (more technical details)... in the end it always looks as a different file to the browser, so it downloads it again

Comment: Why and when would this be used best? I would imagine it better to allow caching to reduce load time; am I wrong?

Comment: @gstricklind Often in development – especially when making frontend changes – caching is your enemy. If your browser caches "old" changes, then you won't be able to tell whether the changes you just made have any effect ("Hm; nothing changed when I refreshed the page. Is that because my code didn't fix anything or because the browser is using cached code?"). When you hit production, though, you want such "cache busting" measures to be disabled because you actually do want the browser to cache your production code.

Comment: Indeed, as @Phoenix says. It's related to dev time. When you need to reduce load time in production, you tune up the page loading by choosing which static resources can and should be cached (often CSS, images and JS fall into that category).