# $debug=true; right after doctype, why?

Tags: php, html, caching

After my question about nearly the same thing after a css file href, I'm guessing the php $debug=true; after doctype also doesn't allow browser caching? If so, I think I understand its use while developing a web site, but is it suppose to be removed once the web site is live? Wouldn't that help load time if content hasn't changed?

Also I've been meaning to find out, how to limit the time frame a browser caches a site or pages? For example after 1 day or 3 hours the stored data will expire.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML><?php $debug=true; ?>
```

Comment: Is this intended as a follow-up to http://stackoverflow.com/q/9220242/212218 ?

Comment: We cannot speak intelligently about code functionality without seeing the code.

Comment: Don't post questions that reference your previous questions, and expect us to know what you're talking about.  Each question should stand on its own, with details.  Either edit the original question, or add details here.

Comment: Having a random string after a css file to break cache doesn't seem like a very elegant solution to begin with.  Having created tons of websites, I've never seen a reason to use anything other than ctrl+f5.

Answer (score 1):

JUST setting `$debug = true;` will not do anything. It's just a variable that you're assigning a boolean value to. However, if you **use** the `$debug` variable like you do in your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9220242/259457), then setting `$debug` to true will cause a random number to be appended to the URL of the CSS file, thus avoiding the browser's cache for that CSS file.

It would be a good idea to turn this debugging off in a production environment in order to allow the browser to use the cached version of the CSS file for quicker page loading. **Or better yet, don't do this at all.** Just find your browser's cache settings and disable caching for your browser. In IE, you can turn it off in the Internet Options. In Firefox, go to `about:config` in your address bar and look for `browser.cache.disk.enable` and set it to false.

As for your second question, I think you are looking for the HTML meta tag [expires](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_meta_http_equiv.asp).

Comment: In addition to this, a quick way to make sure your visitors have the newest CSS file is to append the 'argument' to the URL of the CSS file by yourself with, for example, the date you edited your CSS. So everytime you update your CSS, you update this date, and your visitors will get the new CSS file.

Answer (score 1):

Settting `$debug = true` doesn't do anything on it's own.

In your other question, it prevents caching because every where the variable is used, they modify the URLs to add a random value. If they didn't do this, then the variable would be useless.

It's set "after the doctype" simply because that's near the top of the file, and you want to declare it early on so that it can be used throughout the rest of the page.

Yes, it would help load time if caching is enabled (no random URLs).

Lastly, you can control how long a page gets cached for using the `Expires` header:

```
header('Expires: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', time()+$expires) . ' GMT');
```